# How to convert nested list to object

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When I receive JSON data like

```
[  
    {  
        "id":1,
        "name":"New Island",
        "residents":[  
            {  
                "name":"Paul",
                "age":"25"
            }
        ]
    },
    {  
        "id":2,
        "name":"One Nation",
        "residents":[  
            {  
                "name":"James",
                "age":"23"
            },
            {  
                "name":"Jessica",
                "age":"26"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

drf deserializer makes it to list which contain OrderedDict

But I want to make it to list of class object.

Here are my django models

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Resident(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country', related_name='residents')
```

Comment: You would have to parse your JSON data and pass the information into the class constructor.

Comment: Check serializers in rest framework, `residents` seem another model, so check `depth` in serializers which would help.

Comment: I already deserialized it. It makes list like
0 = OrderedDict([('name', 'New Island'), ('residents', [OrderedDict([('name', 'Paul'), ('age', 25)])])])
1 = OrderedDict([('name', 'One Nation'), ('residents', [OrderedDict([('name', 'James'), ('age', 23)]), OrderedDict([('name': 'Jessica'), ('age', 26)])])])

Comment: What do your serializers looks like ? also I'm not sure what "it" refers to in your question ("drf deserializer makes it to list which contain OrderedDict")

Answer (score 1):

From Python's [JSON library](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html)

```
import json

data = '[{"id":1,"name":"New Island","residents":[{"name":"Paul","age":"25"}]},{"id":2,"name":"One Nation","residents":[{"name":"James","age":"23"},{"name":"Jessica","age":"26"}]}]'

x = json.loads(data)

for each_set in x:
    for every_person in each_set["residents"]:
        print(every_person["name"]) #getting resident's name
        print(every_person["age"])  #getting age
        print(each_set["name"]) #getting the country name
```

From there it's as easy as passing in the proper parameters to classes like

Answer (score 0):

Override the serializer methods that control transformation from primitive to internal http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior